# Change Image Texture Type to "Cubemap" using Unity Scripting API

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Using **Unity Inspector**, it is easy to change **Texture Type** of image to **Cubemap** (Image Attached Below)

[image]

I want to achieve the same using C# script. Googled a lot to find nothing specific.

First, I make a network call to download my panaromic 360 image and wait for it to yield. All good!

```
image = new WWW (subplacesList [this.curSubPlace].getImage ());
while( !image.isDone ) {
    curLoading = image.progress * 100;
    progressImg.fillAmount =  image.progress;
    yield return null;
}
```

The above code gives me **WWW** object. I can convert to **Texture2D Object** using **image.texture** but that is not what I want.

I'm trying to change the image type to Cubemap so that I can apply it to a material and change the skybox.

Note: I have been downloading the image and wrapping it to a Unlit/InsideVisible sphere as an alternative but it's pretty crappy. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you plan to do in the Editor or Editor + build?

Comment: I need to do it in runtime using a C# script

Comment: I know you want to do it during runtime with C#. There is a runtime in Editor when you click play. There is a runtime when you build the project for windows,ios,android....Which one? This seems to be possible in editor runtime only

Comment: I want it when I build it for android. And yes I did come across a few posts saying it is possible only during editor runtime. Have you worked on wrapping texture2d on a sphere?

Comment: Nope. I haven't worked on wrapping texture2d on a sphere.That doesn't sounds crazy to me even though many people do it. As for your question, I think I may be able to help...Is the image you are receiving 6?  If they are 6 images, I can construct them into cubemaps...

Comment: @Programmer Yeah wrapping texture2d on a sphere works fine but the wrapping is crappy at the top and bottom of the sphere. 
And no it is just one single 360 image. Life would have been easier if there were 6 images hehe

Comment: Yes, it would be. What extension is this image? Can you provide a link to it or image like it? I want to see if I can do some magic....

Comment: Is this problem solved?

Comment: @Programmer Nope! Found a work around and found it works well for me. I used the traditional method of applying texture to a sphere. And additionally found some new shader tweaks that helped me out.